# How to export SharePoint 2007 AD Accounts to Excel

Tags: 2007, active-directory, excel

Is there any way to export SharePoint 2007 AD accounts to Excel? I know that there are couple of ways to export SharePoint Userinfo list to Excel. But i want to export SharePoint 2007 Active Directory accounts to Excel? Any idea to do this ?

Comment: What are SharePoint AD accounts? With Windows authentication, SharePoint uses the AD credentials, so users don't have to log in again. SharePoint does not keep its own AD accounts. Step back and explain what you want to achieve. Why export?

Comment: I actually want to export login names like "Domain\User" from Userinfo list to Excel. Is that possible?

Comment: Normal lists can be exported to Excel. Not sure about the User Information list. Still, what do you want to achieve? Why export? What's behind all this? Active Directory will have all your users. SharePoint will only have the ones that have logged on to the site collection.

Comment: I know we can export Userinfo list to Excel, look here:http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.se/2012/03/export-sharepoint-user-groups-in-excel.html. Under this link, we can export userinfo list to excel but i was not able to export account column i.e login names like "Domain\user". How i can export this account column ?